# Convert log model to linear model

Tags: linear-regression

I have a log-log model as follows:

> ln quality = ln price + predictor_2 + predictor_3

I ran a regression and using the coefficient values obtained, I predicted log quality values and then I plotted a curve of predicted log quality (y-axis) vs. log price (x-axis). I feel it is better to have a plot of predicted quality vs. price (instead of the log of these variables). Can I use the same coefficients obtained from the log-log model regression to predict quality using price (note: not the log of price), predictor_2 and predictor_3 values? Or should I apply some conversion formula to obtain different coefficient values for the independent variables?

Comment: So you have a regression. $log q= \alpha \log p + \beta x_1+\gamma x_2$, and you want to use $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$  to predict $q$ (not $\log q$) as a function of $p$ (not $\log p$). You can just exponentiate both sides to obtain $q=  p^\alpha e^{x_1+x_2} $. This is just a transformation, I am not sure it does anything useful. In fact, it is not useful to interpret the regression as you would normally do because of the inclusion of  $e^{x_1+x_2}$ as a term

Comment: @tintinthong, Thanks for this. This helps. It's just that a plot of q vs. p is more intuitive to interpret than log q vs. log p. Also, shouldn't the transformed equation be >q=p^α e^βx1 e^γx2?

Comment: No probs. Yes you are spot on. I made a mistake there

Answer (score 1):

Your true model being $$q=p^ \alpha\,e^{\beta x_1+\gamma x_2} \tag 1$$ for conveniency you made it linear using a logarithmic transform $$\log (q)= \alpha \log( p) + \beta x_1+\gamma x_2\tag 2$$ But you must take care that these two models are not the same since you minimize with respect to the parameters $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ two different objective functions $$SSQ_1=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(p_i^ \alpha\,e^{\beta x_{1i}+\gamma x_{2i}} -q_i\right)^2$$ 
$$SSQ_2=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\alpha \log (p) + \beta x_{1i}+\gamma x_{2 i}-\log(q_i)\right)^2$$ and this is not the same story.

If you want to be rigorous, since using $(2)$ you have reasonable and consistent estimates, use them as initial values for a nonlinear regression.

In fact, if the errors are small, you could demonstrate that using $(2)$ is almost equivalent to a minimization of the sum of the squares of  the *relative* errors on $q$ while $(1)$ corresponds to the minimization of the sum of the squares of  the *absolute* errors on $q$ (which, I suppose, is your goal).

If you do not want to use nonlinear regression, you could use what is proposed [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html) which is easy to extend to your case (three linear equations for your three parameters). It would be a good compromise between $(1)$ and $(2)$.