# Interpret model estimates after log transformation

Tags: statistics, logarithms, linear-regression

I sat up a mixed-effects linear model with the dependent variable log-transformed (in oder to get it normal distributed and as ist is common with this kind of data in other publications). All fixed affects are significant and a consequent multiple comparissons of means works also great (significant differences of log10 values of different treatments). Now I wonder how to interpret the model estimates quantitatively. It seems not correct to just re-transform the estimates. Although the results are in the regular range and the means are in the same order as with untransformed values.
[Only related topic I found is this[][1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401745/convert-log-model-to-linear-model) but I'm not sure if it is applicable to my case.
The formula I use is:

```
log10(y) ~ = 0 + var1:var2 + var1:var2:cov1 + var1:var2:cov2
```

I'm working with R btw.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is a major problem as you noticed in my answer in the linked page. The key problem is that you measure $y$ and not $\log_{10}(y)$; so, if the errors are not very samll, you can face serious dangers. Can't you afford a nonlinear regression since you already have good (or at least reasonable) estimates of the parameters ? It would be much safer.

Comment: @Claude: Thanks for your answer. I specified my question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/402415/interpret-model-estimates-after-log-transformation. If you would be so kind and have a look :)

Comment: @Claude: How to set up a nonlinear regression on basis of my pre-work?

Comment: No idea ! I am not a statistician ... even if I have some experience with data fitting. This expalins my comment. Just a stupid question : can you write $y=10^{xxx}$ ?